# Regex: get all content inc. newline inside tags

Tags: regex

I have some text with bbcode style-tags for localization. I'm need replace content, but i can't match some tags, which contains newline characters

```
**\[([A-Za-z]{2})\](.+?)\[\/[A-Za-z]{2}\]**
```

*My text:*

```
Hello from Landry Bonnefoi and [fr]France[/fr] <----- !!! This content **matched** (France) !!!

[en]sdfsfsdfsfs  <----- !!! This content **Not matched** bause newline !!!
opip

[/en]***
```

I need match ALL content inside tags [] and [/]

Comment: You don't need to escape the forward slash `\/`, its not a regex meta-character.

Answer (score 2):

Use DOTALL modifier `(?s)` to make dot to match even newline characters also.

```
(?s)\[([A-Za-z]{2})\](.+?)\[\/[A-Za-z]{2}\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bO9aL0/1)

Answer (score 1):

It is not returning multiline content because of your use of `.+` that uses everything except newlines. Instead you can use `[\s\S]` to make DOT match newlines.

```
\[([A-Za-z]{2})\]([\s\S]+?)\[\/[A-Za-z]{2}\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to allow for new lines as well inside you tags so you can match them both with this regex.

```
\[(\w{2})\]([^\[]*)\[\/\w{2}\]
```

This will get you both the [fr] and [en] tags.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, use dot-all modifier. Here, its used in-line.

```
 # (?is)\[([a-z]{2})\s*\](.+?)\[/\1\s*\]

 (?is)
 \[
 ( [a-z]{2} )           # (1)
 \s* \]
 ( .+? )                # (2)
 \[/ \1 \s* \]
```